# Validated Protein-Protein interaction database for cancer

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I need to use validated PPI data in my research. Is there any database of such validated (like Mass Spectrometry) database for cancer?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular databases of PPI data is [STRING](https://string-db.org/). It is not only for cancer though, but since many research is done in the field of cancer, you will find a lot of data derived from cancer research.

Answer (score 0):

[OncoPPi](http://oncoppi.emory.edu/)

> This site provides a platform to facilitate discovery of new
>   mechanisms to control tumorigenesis through the **integration of
>   genomic, pharmacological, clinical, and structural data with the
>   network of cancer-associated protein-protein interactions**
>   experimentally detected in cancer cells.

---

Li et al. (2017) *The OncoPPi network of cancer-focused protein-protein interactions to inform biological insights and therapeutic strategies.* Nat Commun 16: [14356](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28205554).